# After requesting 2nd http GET command to get 2nd range, couldn't get any response

Tags: java, http, sockets, httpresponse

I am trying to get whole txt file range by range which is specificly determined. 1st request is successfully completed but when I do second get request to receive the second part, I couldn't get any response, just nulls. Is there a lack of something? I put a while loop to observe if any value will come after nulls, but I couldn't see!

I don't use any special library for this http socket. I just create a socket with port 80 and a bufferedwriter(writer) and bufferedreader(reader) to communicate with server.

This is the whole method. I have updated the question:

```
public static void rangedRequest(String host, String url, int totalPartNum, String outputFile) throws IOException{
    String headRequest = "HEAD " +url+" HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            + "Host: "+ host +"\r\n\r\n";

    Socket sock = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        sock = new Socket(host, 80);
        writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
        reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR:Unknown host");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    writer.write(headRequest);
    writer.flush();
    /***************Response**************/
    String response;
    int totalLength = 0;
    do{
        response = reader.readLine();
        if(response.indexOf("Content-Length") > -1){
            totalLength = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(response.indexOf(' ')+1));
            response = null;
        }
    }while(response != null);
    /****File Length infor is received****/
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    int range = totalLength/totalPartNum;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPartNum; i++) {
        String getRequest = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +            
                "Host: "+ host + "\r\n" + 
                "Range: bytes="+ i*range + "-" + ((i+1)*range -1) +
                "\r\n\r\n";                         //get range query
        writer.write(getRequest);
        writer.flush();
        boolean afterInfo = false;

        while(!reader.ready()){}
        do{       
            response = reader.readLine();
            if(response.indexOf("Range")>-1){       //After some information, there is an empty line and data
                afterInfo = true;                   //To understand info part is reached
            }                
        }while(!(response.length() < 1 && afterInfo));

        while(response != null){
            output.write(response);
            response = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    sock.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you post a complete request/reponse header pair and the response body?

Answer (score 0):

Create new socket, each time you are sending a new request to the Http server. So that you need to reconstruct sock, writer and reader then do the request to the Http server and finally close the socket and shutdown its input and output streams in the loop.

Comment: But I am using HTTP 1.1 not HTTP 1.0. Why do I need to do this?